# Before and after effect with logistic regression, what method to use?

Tags: regression, logistic, treatment-effect

So I have a test subject A which consist of a binary variable 0 and 1. I want to see if this binary variable is decided by some independent variables (plus interactions) which are continuous, which in my case I apply normal logistic regression to see if I can model it.

However after I apply a treatment on test subject A, I want to see if:
- Does the binary variable odds ration effect change after treatment?
- Does the independent variables effects change on the binary variable after treatment

Should I do two different logistic regression models (before and after) and compare its parameters with each other?

Comment: So, $y$ is a function of treatment $D$ and covariates $X$.  You want to know whether $\partial y/\partial X | D = 1$ is the same as $\partial y/\partial X | D = 0$?

Comment: Yes, most likely covariates X have likely changed as well after treatment.

Comment: You probably want a more authoritative answer from someone who uses these methods more, but you might consider a mixed logit.  Basically include both before and after data in the model, include a subject-wise random effect, and include interactions between the before/after variable and each of the X's.

Comment: Any thoughts if I add the before and after effect into one logistic model. I then subject my dependent and independent variables to a dichotmous variable which descirbes 0 for before and 1 for after treatment?